# Proof of differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Q: $f(x)$ continuous in $\mathbb{R}$

Show that  if
$$e^{x+h}f(x+h)-e^xf(x)<h^2 \implies |e^{x+h}f(x+h)-e^xf(x)|<h^2$$

Comment: You have $a<h^2$ implies $|a|<h^2$. To find a counterexample just choose $a<0$ with an absolute value big enough. Then the first inequality always satisfied, whereas the latter is violated.

Answer (score 2):

This is false if $f$ is the constant function $f(x)=-1$, even if $h$ is positive.

Comment: +1, just one question - why does it matter whether $h$ is positive or not?

Comment: If $h$ is negative then $e^{x+h}-e^x$ is negative, so multiplying by $f$ you get positive.